# How do I load CSS files to a custom theme?

Tags: 8, theming

I understand this question has been asked many times. However, I still can't figure out why the CSS files of my custom Drupal 8 theme are not loading.

Edited (more info): The CSS files are not being defined at all (they do not show up in the HTML).

Here is my `test.info.yml` file:

```
name: "test"
type: theme
description: "Theme by ..."
package: custom
core: 8.x

libraries:
  - test/global-styling
  - test/global-scripts

regions:
  headline: Headline
  header: Header
  content_special: 'Content special'
  content: Content
  sidebar: Sidebar
  footer: Footer
```

And here is my `test.libraries.yml` file

```
global-styling:
  version: 1.0
  css:
    theme:
      css/bootstrap-4.0.0.css: {}
      css/content.css: {}
      css/footer.css: {}
      css/header.css: {}
      css/IE.css: {}
      css/lista.css: {}
      css/navigation.css: {}
      css/style.css: {}
      css/taulukko.css: {}

global-scripts:
  version: 1.0
  js:
    js/scripts.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

**Note**: The CSS files are not being defined at all (they do not show up in the HTML). So the console is not showing any errors about this issue. The css files are accessible if you manually type the path in the browser window.

Comment: Looks all good so far. You activated it, flushed caches, and then inspect the HTML on a front-end page, and the CSS and JS ain't there, did I got it right? Did you already tried it with a base theme set in your `test.info.yml`? For example: `base theme: classy`? I'm not sure if `package` is necessary. I'd remove it.

Comment: you has enable it in the admin ?

Comment: Yes, activated theme, flushed caches (like a dozen times) and when I inspect the HTML on the front-end there isn't a single CSS file defined. I now even added a base theme (classy) as you suggested. I appreciate the comments though!

Comment: If you open the network tab of your console, does it show that the CSS files are being not found?

Comment: The CSS files are not being defined at all (they do not show up in the HTML). So the console is not showing any errors about this issue. The css files are accessible if you manually type the path in the browser window.

Comment: Have you implemented html.html.twig? Are you outputting the CSS in that template?

Comment: The last comment of Jaypan would have been my first guess as well: Check, whether your theme overrides the default `html.html.twig` template, and if so whether it contains the `<css-placeholder token="{{ placeholder_token|raw }}">` token in its header.

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot of different things I found the problem in `page.html.twig` file. I had misspelled one region name (a "-" instead of a "_"). Fixing the misspelled region name just got the CSS working.

Thank you all that helped me by commenting on the question.